# Why aren't my "has_many :through" checkboxes updating my third model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, haml

I have 3x models:

```
class Heuristic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :footnotes
  has_many :references, :through => :footnotes
end

class Reference < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :footnotes
  has_many :heuristics, :through => :footnotes
end

class Footnote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reference
  belongs_to :heuristic
end
```

A join table:

```
class CreateFootnotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :footnotes do |t|
      t.integer :heuristic_id
      t.integer :reference_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

A form called from the new reference view:

```
= form_for @reference do |f|
  .field
    = hidden_field_tag "reference[heuristic_ids][]", nil
    - @heuristics.each do |heuristic|
      = label_tag dom_id(heuristic), heuristic.description
      = check_box_tag "reference[heuristic_ids][]", heuristic.id, @reference.heuristics.include?(heuristic), id: dom_id(heuristic)
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

A references controller:

```
  def new
    @reference = Reference.new
    @heuristics = Heuristic.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
    end
  end

  def create
    @reference = Reference.new(params[:reference])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @reference.save
        format.html { redirect_to references_path, notice: 'Reference was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

When you go to the new reference view, select a heuristic and click Save, I expect this to associate the selected heuristic with the reference, but when you drop into rails console you can see that it has not:

```
ref = Reference.last
  Reference Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "references".* FROM "references" ORDER BY "references"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
+----+-----+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
| id |  created_at              | updated_at              |
+----+-----+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
| 2  |  2012-10-29 11:21:24 UTC | 2012-10-29 11:21:24 UTC |
+----+-----+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
1 row in set
1.9.2p318 :002 > ref.heuristics
  Heuristic Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "heuristics".* FROM "heuristics" INNER JOIN "footnotes" ON "heuristics"."id" = "footnotes"."heuristic_id" WHERE "footnotes"."reference_id" = 2
 => [] 
1.9.2p318 :003 > Footnote.all
  Footnote Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "footnotes".* FROM "footnotes" 
 => [] 
1.9.2p318 :004 >
```

Why is this?

Thanks,

Steven.

BTW, I expected the `reference[heuristic_ids][]` to dynamically generate the name of each checkbox, but instead the name of each checkbox is the same: `reference[heuristic_ids][]`.

Comment: can  you check how params is passed in controller it seems to be correct

Comment: {"reference"=>{"heuristic_ids"=>["", "2"]}, "commit"=>"Save", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"references"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the `:heuristic_ids` (virtual) field is accessible:

```
attr_accessible :heuristic_ids # in the model. PLURAL!
```

Then try to do it in the console (with a bang to show any validation error):

```
> Reference.create!("heuristic_ids"=>["", "2"])
```

this way you'll get more information about WHY this doesn't get saved.

Comment: I had `attr_accessible heuristic_id` in `class Footnote < ActiveRecord::Base` and just changed this to `attr_accessible heuristic_ids`, thanks. With the bang, I'm getting the `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: heuristic_ids` error. Am I meant to set `attr_accessible heuristic_id` in any other model?

Comment: As I said, you have to set `attr_accessible :heuristic_ids` with final S.

Answer (score 0):

ah i am having same issue one of my recent project,i didn't dig into too much why "" is coming 
in controller like `params[:reference][:heuristic_ids] = params[:reference][:heuristic_ids].select{|x| x.to_i >0 }`
 or just  `params[:reference][:heuristic_ids].shift`  see whatever it works for you and check.

saving "" id cause validation eror,